Typing JsonValue field
I am using Pydantic and Pydantic Settings, and they have been working very well. However, I have a JSON field in my .env, and using the JSON field it loads correctly (see functional example below). However, I would like to type this JSON field that Pydantic loads. I do not want it to be generic; I want it to have two fields (username and password) in its object. Typing is precisely why I use Pydantic.
Is there any way to do this?
from typing import Deque, List, Optional, Tuple
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic import RedisDsn
from pydantic import JsonValue
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
from pydantic_settings import SettingsConfigDict
from typing import Optional


class Account(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_file=".env",
        env_file_encoding="utf-8",
        extra="ignore",
    )

    accounts: JsonValue = Field(default=..., json_schema_extra=Account.model_json_schema())



settings = Settings()

print(settings.accounts) # I would like it to be possible here to press `.` and have suggestions for username or password come up.

.env
ACCOUNTS={"username": "rodrigo@stackoverflow.com", "password": "abc123"}

